# Create new label in Gmail

Tags: gmail

My wife has an iPhone, she goes to hamburger and "create new label".

I have a Google pixel, I don't have this feature. Or do I, and I'm just being blind?

Answer (score 0):

No you are not being blind.

From: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

In the **Android** tab of:

**Create labels to organize Gmail**

Section named:

**Create, edit & delete labels**

> On a computer, open Gmail. You can't create labels from the Gmail app.

I would suggest sending feedback from the app.

Answer (score 0):

To Add a label to your gmail in other email accounts you own

Open chrome Invoke gmail This will bring you to mobile browser Tap three dots in corner Select go incognito Invoke gmail again Sign in Clock 3 straight lines (top left) Scroll down and select desktop Add label as you would on computer